# Product of Moore Penrose Inverse and Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

Say, we had m x n matrix B. B+ is the Moore Penrose Inverse (pseudoinverse) of the matrix. Would B+B (product of pseudoinverse of B and B) be a projection matrix? How would we prove this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I would use the SVD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the defining properties of Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse, $B^+B$ is Hermitian and
$$
(B^+B)^2=(B^+BB^+)B=B^+B.
$$
Therefore, $B^+B$ is not just a projection, but an *orthogonal* projection.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed.